# Give a boolean an ID using string value

Tags: android, string, boolean

In order for my projects algorithm to work I have to name a boolean the value of the String.  For example:

```
String check="Hello";
Boolean check=true;
if(some condition){
Hello=false;
}
```

//Where the ID of check is "Hello" as defined in the string, I know this is not the way about it which I displayed as an example, Want to know the correct way to implement it.

```
Update-:
```

If you want to use it as a boolean to check if it is true:

```
if(Hashmapboolean.get(StringValue)){
//Action
}
```

This is how you check if the Hashmap shown in the answer is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any of the associative collections Java has to offer. Like a [Map](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map).
This way you can use keys for values.

```
Map<String, Boolean> myMap  = new HashMap();
while (!shouldStopLoop()){
   String  myKeyName = getNextName();
   if (some condition){
      myMap.put(myKeyName, false);
   }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, will try it out and update the answer.

Comment: I'm not able to do this-:
`if(myMap){
//Action
}`
With the boolean

Comment: I even tried `if(myMap.get(true)){ //Some Action }` ...could..Can't I use it like A boolean?